# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0

Tags: java

I want to create a small console program which convert from Celsius - Fahrenheit and vice versa, this is the code I tried:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CelsiusFahrenheit {

    private static Scanner s;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        s = new Scanner(System.in);
        char reponse = 'N', choixConvert;

        do
        {
            do
            {
                System.out.println("Choisie le mode de converstion : ");
                System.out.println("1 - Converstisseur Celesuis - Fahrenheit");
                System.out.println("2 - Converstisseur Fahrenheit - Celesuis");

                do
                {
                    System.out.print("Votre Choix: ");
                    choixConvert = s.next().charAt(0);
                    if(choixConvert != '1' && choixConvert != '2')
                          System.out.println("Mode inconnu, veuillez réitérer votre choix.");
                }
                while(choixConvert!='1' && choixConvert!='2');

                System.out.print("Température à convertir : ");
                double temp = s.nextDouble();
                System.out.print("Resultat est: " + ConvertCelesuisFahrenheit(choixConvert,temp));
                System.out.println("\nSouhaitez-vous convertir une autre température ? (O/N)");
                reponse = Character.toUpperCase(s.nextLine().charAt(0));

            }while(reponse != 'O' && reponse != 'N');
        }while(reponse == 'O');

        System.out.println("Au revoir !");
    }

    private static Double ConvertCelesuisFahrenheit(int choixConvert,double temp )
    {
        if(choixConvert == 1)
            return (9/5)*temp+32;
        else
            return (temp-32)*(5/9);
    }
}
```

but I had a problem that the function ConvertCelesuisFahrenheit() always return 0.0 and after that it gives me this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException:
>   String index out of range: 0  at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown
>   Source)   at CelsiusFahrenheit.main(CelsiusFahrenheit.java:33)

This is the output:

```
Choisie le mode de converstion : 
1 - Converstisseur Celesuis - Fahrenheit
2 - Converstisseur Fahrenheit - Celesuis
Votre Choix: 2
Température à convertir : 33
Resultat est: 0.0
Souhaitez-vous convertir une autre température ? (O/N)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
    at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
    at CelsiusFahrenheit.main(CelsiusFahrenheit.java:33)
```

Comment: I think it'd be a lot easier to answer your question if it weren't so... messy. You have so many do - while loops, honestly you could probably do it in one loop. If you could just show us line 33, that would be better.

Comment: this is the line 33:
`reponse = Character.toUpperCase(s.nextLine().charAt(0));`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`nextDouble()` leaves the newline in the input stream, so when you then call

```
nextLine().charAt(0)
```

the result of `nextLine()` is an empty string. Remove the newline from the stream, or use `next()`, as you did above.

Comment: I tried that but I had this error :
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
 at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
 at CelsiusFahrenheit.main(CelsiusFahrenheit.java:31)`
The line 31 : `s.nextLine().charAt(0);`

Comment: What did you try? Of course, even if you remove the newline, if the next line the scanner gets is empty, you'll get the same exception.

Comment: I did this : `double temp = s.nextDouble();
    s.nextLine().charAt(0);`

Comment: That doesn't remove the newline from the stream at all. I strongly advise you to use `next()` instead of `nextLine()` there to ensure you don't get an empty line.

Comment: Okey my problem has been solved I replaced double `s.nextLine();` by `s.next();`

Answer (score 2):

There's several problems here ..

`nextLine().charAt(0)` gets the empty string because the new line is not consumed by nextDouble()

You can fix this by simply adding a

```
String continueString = s.next();
response = Character.toUpperCase(continueString.charAt(0));
```

In addition, the math in your conversion calculation is incorrect. Use `5.0/9.0` instead of `5/9`.

Finally, you are reading the `choixConvert` character as a `char` , but then passing it as an `int` into your method, so the `else` block will always execute.

Comment: Okey thanks I have correct all those problems, but the main problem didn't solved

Answer (score 1):

Update this: `reponse = Character.toUpperCase(s.nextLine().charAt(0));` with

```
          String line = s.nextLine();
          while(line.length() <1){
             line = s.nextLine();
          }
          reponse = Character.toUpperCase(line.charAt(0));
```

Comment: I did this but I had the same error

Comment: @SuSha At same line? It should be coming from different line now.

Comment: My problem has been solved the problem was the nextLine() I should use next()

Comment: @SuSha Good to know. Hope that you got the differences as well. `next` reads the next string while `nextList` reads the entire line. I am hopeful, you can fix you program using nextLine as well.