# StringIndexOutOfBoundsException String index out of range error

Tags: java, string, syntax-error, indexoutofboundsexception

I am getting this error when I enter the String "s" after entring an integer.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
    at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
    at oneB.change(oneB.java:4)
    at oneB.main(oneB.java:26)
```

Following is the code: (Please note that the code is still complete and I have entered some print statements for checking)

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class oneB {
    public static String change(int n, String s, String t) {

        if (s.charAt(0) == 'R') {
            return onetwo(s);
        }
        return s;
    }
    private static String onetwo(String one) {
        int c = one.indexOf('C');
        System.out.print(c);
        char[] columnarray = new char[one.length() - c - 1];
        for (int i = c + 1; i < one.length(); i++) {
            columnarray[i] = one.charAt(i);
        }
        int columnno = Integer.parseInt(new String(columnarray));
        System.out.print(columnno);
        return one;

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System. in );
        int n = in .nextInt();
        String s = in .nextLine();
        String t = in .nextLine();
        System.out.print(change(n, s, t));
    }

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14708231/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-stringindexoutofboundsexception-string-ind) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13021297/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-stringindexoutofboundsexception-string-ind

Comment: @AmanArora please see my answer that will fix your problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The call `in.nextInt()` leaves the endline character in the stream, so the following call to `in.nextLine()` results in an empty string. Then you pass an empty string to a function that references its first character and thus you get the exception.

Comment: Being a beginner, I barely understood what you are saying. could you suggest the edit in my code which would make it run?

Comment: Add one more `in.nextLine()` immediately after the line `n = in.nextInt();`

Comment: And you should also protect your `change()` method from receiving an empty string - so the condition should be `if (!s.isEmpty() && s.charAt(0) == 'R')`

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I debugged it:

- You are getting a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` with index zero at line 4.
- That means that the String you are operating on when you call `s.charAt(0)` is the empty String.
- That means that `s = in.nextLine()` is setting `s` to an empty String.

How can that be?  Well, what is happening is that the previous `nextInt()` call read an integer, but it left the characters after the integer unconsumed.  So your `nextLine()` is reading the remainder of the line (up to the end-of-line), removing the newline, and giving you the rest ... which is an empty String.

Add an extra `in.readLine()` call before you attempt to read the line into `s`.

Comment: Like I said - "... before you attempt to read the line into s".

Answer (score 1):

One another solution to the problem would be instead of `nextLine()`, use just `next()`.

```
        int n = in .nextInt();
        String s = in .next();
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `s` is an empty String `""`.

Answer (score 0):

```
   for (int i = c + 1; i < one.length(); i++) {
        columnarray[i] = one.charAt(i);   // problem is here.
    }
```

You need to start array index from 0. But you are starting from c + 1

```
    for (int i = c + 1,j=0; i < one.length(); i++,j++) {
        columnarray[j] = one.charAt(i);
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you hit enter, your int is followed by a '\n' character. Just modify the code like this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System. in );
    int n = in .nextInt();
    in.nextLine(); //This line consume the /n afer nextInt
    String s = in .nextLine();
    String t = in .nextLine();
    System.out.print(change(n, s, t));
}
```