# Can't receive user input within a switch statement

Tags: java, exception, switch-statement, user-input

I am just starting to write a menu which requires a user to choose which operation they want to carry out (like pages etc.). Once they have chosen the operation they need to be able to input with the keyboard to complete the task.

The problem is that I am receiving a 'StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range' message when the user tries to input. Here is the code:

```
int choice;
  boolean finished= false;
  while (!finished) {
     System.out.println(currentUser.getFirstName() + ". Please choose: ");
     System.out.println("'l'- To like a page, 'e' to exit");
     choice = keyboard.nextLine().charAt(0);
     switch (choice) {
        case 'l':
           PageList.displayAllPages();
           System.out.println("Enter the page to add");
           int pIndex = keyboard.nextInt();
           currentUser.insertPage(PageList.findPage(pIndex).toString());
           break;
        case 'e':
           finished = true;
           currentUser.saveMyPages(userDir);
           currentUser.saveMyFriends();
           break;
        default:
           System.out.println("Invalid entry");
     }//switch
  }//while
```

Obviously the problem is:

```
int pIndex = keyboard.nextInt();
currentUser.insertPage(PageList.findPage(pIndex).toString());
```

How can I fix this? Do I need to put it in a try catch statement?

Here is the trace. Line 79 is actually the line beginning 'choice = keyboard' before the switch statement

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
>       at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:646)
>       at B00670983.SocNetApp.main(SocNetApp.java:79)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)

Comment: At what line is the Exception being thrown? Please provide the stacktrace.

Comment: Also, if you claim that the problem is with the insertPage/findPage function calls, you'll have to provide their implementations as well.

Comment: I've added the trace to the question. The insertPage and findPage function calls have been fully tested and are working so not sure if they need to be posted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After execution of the line

```
int pIndex = keyboard.nextInt();
```

at the the second iteration of while-loop you still have endline character in the input stream and

```
choice = keyboard.nextLine().charAt(0);
```

results in an empty string.
So add one more `keyboard.nextLine();` after the line

```
int pIndex = keyboard.nextInt();
```

See for [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18916959/stringindexoutofboundsexception-string-index-out-of-range-error)

Comment: That's fixed it. Nikita I love you very much! Have yourself a drink and imagine I paid for it... :-)))